# Dotnet build of solution containing projects with different target frameworks

Tags: .net, csproj, solution, sln-file

I have a solution containing multiple projects. To simplify:

The Gui project targets `net7.0-android` and `net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0`

The Library project targets `net7.0` and is referenced by the  Gui project.

The problem is that I can't launch a solution-wide build, e.g. `dotnet publish -f net7.0-android`, because I'll get the infamous error:

```
error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'library\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net7.0-android'.
```

But if I launch the build by explicitly passing the Gui project, it works: `dotnet publish ./library/library.csproj -f net7.0-android`

This workaround is quite clumsy and won't compile other projects that are not dependencies of the Gui one (e.g. the Tests project).

Is there a way to tell the compiler that "If a dependency doesn't target the passed framework, use `net7.0` as default"?

Maybe I'm wrong, but it doesn't feel right to me to target multiple targets in the library project, since it's a generic library and the `net7.0` target is just enough. Also, the Gui project build works exactly as I would expect, so the same behavior for the solution-wise build would be very appreciated.